# How to fix Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when using Convolutional layers in pytorch, error on backward()

Tags: pycharm, pytorch, conv-neural-network, cudnn

When I use `Conv1d` or `Conv2d` layers on `pytorch`, the process is killed unexpectedly. I am getting the error in the following line:

```
loss.backward()
```

**My set up:**

- Windows 10
- cuda 10.2
- cudnn 7.6.5
- RTX 2060 Super
- Nvidia driver 451.67
- Pycharm 2020.04

**Error:**

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

In comparison, when I replace the `conv` layer with a `dense` layer, the problem doesn't occur.

For more comparison, the same project and the same code was run on `Ubuntu 20.04` as well, and it worked quite well.

Comment: Try running the same code just in the console without PyCharm, I've found that PyCharm will give cryptic crash code messages and no stack trace for certain libraries like PyQt and PyTorch

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a known [bug](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/sudden-exit-on-relatively-small-model-gpu/37071/12) around this problem that happens with `Pytorch` on windows, when run on GPU(with `CUDA`) .

Ensure all params supplied to `Conv1d` and `Conv2d` are correct especially `padding` value. Note that it can have different behaviour with other OS like linux/ubuntu.

And also if you are using `Python-3.6` or higher version, it could be this [bug](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/please-help-me-solve-this-error-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005/57932). In that case try with `Python-3.5`